# How to take a build of python project to deploy it as a website for public?

Tags: python, django, windows, build, pycharm

I am very much interested to learn python and do more projects in it. As a starting, I did a small django app. It runs on my local machine successfully. I need to know how to take a build of my project to deploy it as a web site for public.

I used `python .6.6`, `django`, `pycharm`
I did my project in Windows 10

Comment: Look into Heroku, Google App Engine or AWS Beanstalk for example.

Comment: First of all this is not a programming related question and can be closed. Coming to your question, If you want to deploy for free then heroku has a free service. And also Google App engine, but you need to create google pay account to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using heroku, it is free for the first five apps and well documented, but I guess there are many many other possibilities like aws.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python